# Appium c# windows shows an exception: Currently only pen and touch pointer input source types are supported

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-desktop

This code throws the exception: **Currently only pen and touch pointer input source types are supported**

```
Actions actionRightClick = new Actions(session);
actionRightClick.Build();
actionRightClick.MoveToElement(windowsElement);
actionRightClick.Click();
actionRightClick.ContextClick();
actionRightClick.Perform();
```

Same with a **desctopSession** and with **DoubleClick**. Any idea?

Additional I tried to find the second windows key for calling the context menu via keys. No idea which code I've to use.

Comment: In my situation I just want to right click to open menu, then I tried to open the context menu by pressing button such as: `driver.pressKeyCode(93); # https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/press-keycode/` 



93 = context menu button, so how do I know? just find some online tool key code detector

Answer (score -1):

Running Windows Application Driver in a console app instead of using Appium Desktop fixed this issue.